# How to change the language without leaving the application on SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, ios16

I want to make a modern language change, but I don’t know how to restart the application, or rather I know, but for me it works with an error and not the way I want. In other applications I saw that the language is updated without leaving the application, the slider is just spinning and that’s it, the language replaced. How to achieve this in SwiftUI?

This is how I run the application:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
 struct MyApp_UkraineApp: App {
    @StateObject var appSettings = AppSettings()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainMenuView()
                .environmentObject(appSettings)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I change languages:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainMenuView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var appSettings: AppSettings
        
    var body: some View {
                HStack {
                    Button("Ukraine") {
                        Language.selected = .ukraine
                        resetApp()
                    }
                    Button("English") {
                        Language.selected = .english
                        resetApp()
                    }
                }
    
    func resetApp() {
        if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
            if let windowSceneDelegate = scene.delegate as? UIWindowSceneDelegate {
                windowSceneDelegate.window??.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: MainMenuView())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum Language: String, CaseIterable {
    case english, ukraine

    var code: String {
        switch self {
        case .english: return "en"
        case .ukraine: return "uk"
        }
    }

    static var selected: Language {
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set([newValue.code], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: "language")
        }
        get {
            return Language(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "language") ?? "") ?? .english
        }
    }

    static func switchLanguageBetweenEnglishAndGerman() {
        selected = selected == .english ? .ukraine : .english
    }
}
```

I get this error, I know why it appears, but I don’t know how to fix it:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type AppSettings found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for AppSettings may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

But the main question is how to make sure that there is a modern language update without restarting the application?

Comment: Don’t use rootViewController, this is against SwiftUI’s pattern, you are breaking the environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `environment(\.locale, ...)` at the root of your app to set language.

The environment is not directly settable though, so you will need to store the setting somewhere (in an `@Observable` or `ObservableObject`).

```
@Observable
class LanguageSetting {
    // initialise this from UserDefaults if you like
    var locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
}
```

```
// in your App conformance
@State var languageSettings = LanguageSetting()

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environment(languageSettings)
            .environment(\.locale, languageSettings.locale)
    }
}
```

When you want to change the language:

```
@Environment(LanguageSetting.self) var languageSettings

var body: some View {
    Button("Chinese Simplified") {
        // code to update user defaults omitted...

        languageSettings.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh-Hans")
    }
}
```

See the [Observation migration guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro) for how to do this with `ObservableObject`.

Comment: Why doesn’t this code change the language of this line? The language changes everywhere, but the set of words based on the language does not change.

`Locale.preferredLanguages.first?.starts(with: "uk") == true ? WordsData().ukraineWords : WordsData().englishWords`

Comment: @OleksiiRuban I’m pretty sure your app cannot change `Locale.preferredLanguages`. It’s based on the users’ settings in the settings app. How about just use the `locale` environment for this too?

Comment: I was thinking about this, I want the user to start with the language that is installed on his phone when he first launches the application. For this I use this code:

`@AppStorage("local") var localeIdentifier: String = "auto"
    var locale: Locale {
        get { if localeIdentifier == "auto" {
                return Locale.current } else {
                return Locale(identifier: localeIdentifier)  }
 } 
set { localeIdentifier = newValue.identifier  }
}`

But now I don’t know how to set the condition for which words to display, because my identifier is “auto”, not “en” or “uk”.

Comment: @OleksiiRuban How is that relevant to `preferredLanguages`? Anyway, rather than just `return Locale.current` when it is `"auto"`, also set the `AppStorage` to `Locale.current.identifier`. I would suggest posting a new question if you are still having problems. Remember to include a [mcve].

Comment: I'll try to do this, thank you very much for your help.